# How to stop Lync from appearing in frequent application list

Tags: windows-7, lync

I have Microsoft Lync 2010 installed on my Windows 7 computer and it is set to start when Windows starts.

This setting causes Lync to get in most frequent used application list in the start menu. Lync is never started manually and even when I explicitly remove Lync from the frequently used application list it finds itself a way back in after a number of reboots. (naturally)

How can I keep it out of my frequent app list?

Comment: I think removing it from Startup will solve the problem, you can remove it from auto-start using `msconfig`, Press Win key and type msconfig.

Comment: No, I still want it to start with Windows. Imjust don't want it in the frequent app list.

Comment: Try if it works on Windows 7 also, http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/window-on-windows/manage-the-most-frequently-used-programs-list-on-your-xp-start-menu/722

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't. There are many post on internet saying it should, but I can't get it to work on Win7.

Comment: That is strange, because that is the way by which windows prevent explorer  (runs almost always) and many other inbuilt programs from coming up in the list. Can you elaborate exactly what changes you did to the registry ?

Comment: I've added a new string NoStartPage value under the keys Lync.exe and Communicator.exe. I also thought this rechnieuq may only prevent future MFU entries but not exclude existing ones so I manually removed "Microsoft Lync 2010" from Start Menu MFU app list after registry update. As soon as Lync starts, it is back into MFU list.

Comment: Try this find the location of Executable that is used at the Startup. And then you will need to create a Shortcut on your own to that Executable. And point the auto-run to that shortcut.(I hope it makes sense)